# Bind an event function to a class but using removeEventListener and removing the references allowing the garbagecollector to work correctly

Tags: javascript, dom-events

As we all know when we create a class in JavaScript a normal function returns the class object but events return the event object and the class object gets lost:

```
function class(a){
 this.name=a;
 document.addEventListener('click',this.click,false);
 xhr.addEventListener('load',this.xhr,false);
 this.normal()
}
class.prototype={
 click:function(e){
  //e=event,this=theDocument //can't access class
 },
 xhr:function(e){
  //e=event,this=theXHR //can't access class
 },
 normal:function(e){
  //e=null,this=class
 }
}
```

Whats the best way to bind those events to our class?

By best way I mean no or just a tiny reference, the ability to remove the events in a native way (`removeEventListener`) and to absolutely not create memory leaks.

1. to remove an eventlistener you need to pass the function as a reference, so `addEventListener('click',function(){alert('something')},false)` does not work.
2. I read references like `var that=this` inside functions create leaks; true?

Known ways:

```
function class(a){
 this.name=a;
 var that=this;// reference
 //simply reference the whole object as a variable.
 
 var bindedClick=this.click.bind(this);//bind the click to the class
 //(js 1.85)
 //can i use removeEventListener('click',bindedClick,false) later?
 //apply && call (js 1.3)
}
```

As I'm not sure if `var that=this` (as it is the whole object) creates leaks, sometimes I minimize this by saving the info into an array and as reference I use a id:

```
var class={};
var id='ID'+Date.now();

class[id].info={here i store all the info i need later text only}
//this will be stored also in a cookie / Localstorage to reuse later.

class[id].dom={here i store the dom references}
class[id].events{here i store the xhr events}//if needed
//this are Temp only
```

and to get the info I just pass the id by adding it to the event element:

```
class[id].events.xhr.id=id;
class[id].events.xhr.onload=class.f

class.prototype.f=function(e){
 //this.response,class[this.id]<- access everything.
 this.removeEventListener('load',class.f,false);
 delete class[this.id].events.xhr;
 delete this.id
}

class[id].dom.id=id;
class[id].dom.onclick=class.f2

class.prototype.f2=function(e){
 //class[e.target.id],class[this.id]<- access everything.
 this.removeEventListener('click',class.f2,false);
 delete class[this.id].dom;
 delete this.id
}
```

As you can see in this example above I have access to everything and the reference is just a small string.

I store the DOM because I define the DOM references on load so I don't have to call `getElementById()` every time.

I store the events like XHR in the class as I want to be able to call `xhr.abort()` from outside, and also able to call `removeEventListener`.

I need to minimize the impact to the memory but at the other side I need to control many elements that have multiple simultaneous events to control the garbage collector "manually" by removing all events and references.

To make sure you understand that the problem is bigger than it looks:
it's a download manager for Chrome. Input field for download URL:

1. `xhr` to get the fileinfo (size, name, acceptranges, mime)
2. store info in localstorage and cached array
3. create visual DOM elements to show progress (event:progress, click, mouseover..)
4. `xhr` request a chunk 0-1000 (event:load)
5. onprogress display progress data (event:progress,error)
6. request filesystem(event:ok,error)
7. readfile/check file (event:ok,error)
8. request filewriter (event:ok,error)
9. append to file (events=ok,error)
10. on ok start again from 3. until file is finished
11. when finished I delete all the **references / events / extra info**
    //this to help the garbage collector.
12. change the DOM contents.

Every file has sooo many events every sec.

**Which of these 3 is the best solution or are there any better solutions?**

```
bind();//or call / apply

var that=this; //reference to the whole object

var id=uniqueid; // reference to the object's id
```

**BASED ON the answers:**

```
(function(W){
 var D,dls=[];
 function init(){
  D=W.document;
  dls.push(new dl('url1'));
  dls.push(new dl('url2'));
 }
 function dl(a){
  this.MyUrl=a;
  var that=this;
  var btn=D.createElement('button');
  btn.addEventListener('click',this.clc,false);
  D.body.appendChild(btn);
 }
 dl.prototype={
  clc:function(e){
    console.log(that)
  }
 }
 W.addEventListener('load',init,false);
})(window)
```

`var that=this` does not work.

This works; but I need a lot of checks, switch if and execute multiple functions.

```
(function(W){
 var D,dls=[];
 function init(){
  D=W.document;
  dls.push(new dl('url1'));
  dls.push(new dl('url2'));
 }
 function dl(a){
  this.MyUrl=a;
  this.btn=D.createElement('button');
  btn.addEventListener('click',this,false);
  D.body.appendChild(btn);
 }
 dl.prototype={
  handleEvent:function(e){
   e.target.removeEventListener('click',this,false);//does this the work?
   return this.clc(e);
  },
  clc:function(e){
   console.log(this,e)
  }
 }
 W.addEventListener('load',init,false);
})(window)
```

BIND :

```
(function(W){
 var D,dls=[];
 function init(){
  D=W.document;
  dls.push(new dl('url1'));
  dls.push(new dl('url2'));
 }
 function dl(a){
  this.MyUrl=a;
  this.clcB=this.clc.bind(this);
  this.btn=D.createElement('button');
  this.btn.addEventListener('click',this.clcB,false);
  D.body.appendChild(this.btn);
 }
 dl.prototype={
  clc:function(e){
   e.target.removeEventListener('click',this.clcB,false);//does this the work?
   delete this.clcB;
   console.log(this)
  }
 }
 W.addEventListener('load',init,false);
})(window)
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Better solution is to have your "class" implement the *EventListener* interface.

You do this by adding a `handleEvent` method to `MyClass.prototype`. This allows you to pass the object directly to `.addEventListener()` instead of passing a handler.

When an event occurs, the `handleEvent()` method will be invoked, with your object as the `this` value. This allows you to have access to all the properties/methods of the object.

```
function MyClass(a) {
    this.name = a;

    // pass the object instead of a function
    document.addEventListener('click', this, false);
    xhr.addEventListener('load', this, false); // where did `xhr` come from?

    this.normal()
}

MyClass.prototype = {

    // Implement the interface
    handleEvent: function(e) {
        // `this` is your object
        // verify that there's a handler for the event type, and invoke it
        return this[e.type] && this[e.type](e);
    },

    click: function (e) {
        // `this` is your object
    },
    load: function (e) {
        // `this` is your object
    },
    normal: function (e) {
        // `this` is your object
    }
}
```

Notice that I changed the name of your `xhr` method to `load`. This makes it easier to call the proper method based on the event type.

Then when it comes time to call `.removeEventListener()`, just do it like normal from the element, but again pass the object instead of the handler.

Comment: yeah but don't i loosethe reference to the domelement? also i'm always using this.response in xhr..

Comment: @cocco: You get reference to the element via `e.currentTarget`, or just make it a property on your object... as long as you clean up if the element is removed from the DOM.

Comment: is handleEvent a native thing?

Comment: i mean how does document.addEventListener('click', this, false); execute the handleEvent function?

Comment: @cocco: Yes, browsers that implement `addEventListener` implement this feature *(the EventListener Interface)* as part of it.

Comment: @cocco: When you pass `this`, it stores that object internally instead of storing the function you would have passed. Then when an event occurs, it looks up the `handleEvent` method on the object, and invokes it.

Comment: huh that's insane... changed the whole way of creatingstufff.. i never heard of this 'handleEvent' ... which browsers support it?

Comment: @cocco: All browsers that support `.addEventListener()` support it, so most browsers. If you're supporting IE8, you can shim it. IMO, it's the one feature that really encourages organized structure in a complex application.

Comment: thats very cool for small stuff..butwhat you think about the solution var that = this? better?

Comment: @cocco: I see this approach as being most useful in larger, complex applications. No, I'd not use `var that = this;`. Newer features were created in order to prevent having to do that.

Comment: it get's hard when xhr asks first time only the info and the second time it asks for a binary chunk

Comment: but: var that=this creates a reference. handleEvent needs many if,swich and also executes a function before passing the event function.

Comment: what about the speed of execution and memory usage?

Comment: @cocco: If you have two independent xhr requests you probably should use independent listeners. Create them with `.bind`.

Comment: @cocco: Think of your application in terms of structure. If your `xhr` object is serving two different purposes, perhaps you should have two new classes for two separate xhr objects based on their role in the application. Or maybe just two plain xhr objects held by a single class. All depends on the application.

Comment: check the EDIT i made

Comment: @cocco: You can't create a variable local to one function and use it inside another. That's why `var that = this` doesn't work.

Comment: hm yeah .. right.. but i need it from inside that one.. so this-that is again out of the games.

Comment: @cocco: You need to understand that every approach has some overhead somewhere. I think you're far too concerned with performance here. How many click events do you think a user can do per second? Certainly not 1000. But even if they could, you'd still not notice any performance impact from any of the approaches you've considered.

Comment: it's more about the xhr requests... but yeah i'm just search a bulletproof reference to myclass.

Comment: also added the bind version, wich one of the last 2  versions is better?

Comment: looks like if i have to many events in one 'dl' and so i need to check to many things ... bind() wins... else hadleEvent is a very powerfull way to do this as it takes prolly much less memory than bind().

Answer (score 1):

> I read references like `var that=this` inside functions create leaks

Wrong. They create references that are not garbage-collected until the function is, but that's exactly what you want. It's not a leak.

It might cause problems in very old browsers (IE6) that cannot handle cyclic references, but simply don't care about those. Also, by calling `removeEventListener` you even destroy that cyclic reference so everything is fine.

> I minimize this by saving the info into an array and the reference is just a small string...

No. The reference is your `class` array which will much more likely create a leak if you forget to `delete` the ids from id. Don't overcomplicate this.

> Which of these 3 is the best solution or are there any better solutions?
>
> ```
> var that=this; //reference to the whole object
> ```

The standard approach. Very fine.

> ```
> .bind();
> ```

Can be more concise than a `that` variable, and has the same reference layout (no difference in garbage collection). Notice that a native `bind` is not available on old browsers, so some people frown upon this method. Fine as well, but might need a shim.

> ```
> var id=uniqueid; // reference to the object's id
> ```

Don't do that. It's too complicated, and you easily make mistakes that really lead to huge leaks.

> The event listener interface with a `handleEvent` method ([presented by @CrazyTrain](https://stackoverflow.com/a/18276825/1048572))

Very elegant, but unknown to the most people. Low memory footprint since no bound, privileged functions need to be created. Works very well for classes that need to handle only one event type, but needs some kind of delegation when supporting different events or different targets with the same listener instance (and can become more complex than the other approaches). Contra: The `handlerEvent` method is public and everything that has access to your instance can "fire" (spoof) events.

---

> var that=this does not work.

You're using it wrong. The point of this approach is to create a closure *in which* new functions have access to the `that` variable. The closure scope is your constructor, you cannot access it from the prototype.

```
var that=this;
btn.addEventListener('click',function(e){that.clc(e);},false);

// use `this` in the prototype
```

> `handleEvent` works... but i need alot of checks , swich if and execute multiple functions.

No. Your instances do only handle the `click` of the button, so this approach is fine for you. You even could put all of your code from `clc` directly into `handleEvent`.

Comment: yeah if 'that' does not create leaks ... it's the best way?... bind() is prolly much slower.?

Comment: @cocco: Not measurably, if at all. I'd guess it's slower on function instantiation but faster when the method is invoked. It won't matter for performance.

Comment: I'm surprised that you find the *EventListener* approach to be unusable when you have different event listeners. Perhaps I'm not understanding what you're getting at.

Comment: @CrazyTrain: I mean your `MyClass` example where you're adding the instance as a handle both to `click` events on the dom and to the `load` event of an xhr. You need some kind of `switch(e.type) {case "click":/*do one thing*/ case "load":/*do other thing*/ }` statement then (or some kind of delegation). Adding distinct listener functions would be simpler in the most cases.

Comment: Hmmm... I guess I find that the single line implementation of `handleEvent()` that I show makes it very clean and simple. It just requires that you name the methods after the event type, or use something like a prefixed version. `return this["_handle_" + e.type] && ...`

Comment: but yeah if i have many clickable elements it's getting bored.

Comment: so which one is better? that=this is more direct... and i don't execute other functions swiches and checks...

Comment: @CrazyTrain: Oops, I should've read your example better - you're already using delegation :-/ Let's say you're going to handle lots of different targets but with the same event type… My point was only that at some point the delegation overhead might become too big, depending on the executed actions.

Comment: which is the fastest one ? you get both +1 ... but i don't know wich one is faster less memoery using.

Comment: @cocco: I already answered that. Performance does not matter (no measurable differences), and the EventListener interface needs least memory.

Comment: @Bergi: I'd think that there would be a separate instance of the class for each target, but I guess it depends on the situation. That would add to the memory overhead, but I've a feeling that cocco is being concerned about nothing with the performance questions.

Comment: sec and i wrtie it down,

Comment: @CrazyTrain: I agree, different smaller instances should be favoured over a god module. Nonetheless, sometimes you need to couple lots of async logic and routing everything through one `handleEvent` method is inadvisable :-)

Comment: Yeah, I'm sure there are occasions where it wouldn't be the best approach. Overloading one class with too much behavior wouldn't be a very good design.

Comment: wait it does not work ... i add the code i just made. based on your answer

Comment: check the EDIT i made

Comment: @Bergi in my case var that=this does not work... i added two examples how i wanna structure the start of the function.

Comment: yeah i was thinking of putting the code inside the handleEvent... anyway in your example i can't remove the eventlistener.

Comment: also added the bind version (wich one of the last 2  versions is better?)

Comment: looks like if i have to many events in one 'dl' and so i need to check to many things ... bind() wins... else hadleEvent is a very powerfull way to do this as it takes prolly much less memory than bind().